# is there any relationship between drawing graphics and IIS overloading

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api, silverlight, iis

I'm running gis web application built on silverlight but when many users connect to the system the IIS reaches the full memory so could the reason be from many users draw graphics at the same time ,if not what could makes the IIS overloaded and not responding.

regrads.

Answer (score 2):

With the information you have provided, I would not be suspecting the drawing of graphics as the issue, as this is all done client-side.  I would be doing some monitoring of the machine that has IIS on it.

Using either Task Manager or/and [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), keep an eye on the lsass and w3wp processes, and see if they bottom out when your also getting lots of hits from your users.  You may need to separate the ArcGIS Web Services into its own application pool

You have not mentioned your ArcGIS Server version, but I would recommend following the steps in these whitepapers, depending on the outcome of your monitoring.

- [On Windows 2008 Server, Vista, or 7, lsass.exe grows in CPU usage and memory utilization under heavy load](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37566)
- [W3WP and SOM processes consume too much memory when GIS services are under heavy load](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/34872)
- [On Windows 2003 Server, the Local Security Authority Subsystem Service (lsass.exe) grows in CPU usage and memory utilization under heavy load](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32620)

Comment: thanks Simon for your answer and my ArcGIS version is 10.0

Answer (score 0):

Just drawing the Graphics should not be the source of the Issue, since they will be in the clients memory, and not on the server.

But if you are doing more than just drawing the graphics on the map, like saving it on the server, or logging it and so on, that could be a problem.